# Error installig Ruby 2.4.1 with rbenv in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I have the following error trying to install Ruby with rbenv:

```
egroj97@SmallFootIV:~$ rbenv install 2.4.1
Downloading ruby-2.4.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby-2.4.1.tar.bz2
error: failed to download ruby-2.4.1.tar.bz2

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.04 using ruby-build 20170726-7-g16aa672)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-  build.20170825083100.28792
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20170825083100.28792.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/ruby-build.20170825083100.28792 ~
curl: (18) transfer closed with 2928469 bytes remaining to read
```

The only thing that appears in the ruby-build.20170825083100.28792.log file is:

```
/tmp/ruby-build.20170825083100.28792 ~
curl: (18) transfer closed with 2928469 bytes remaining to read
```

I guess the problem is because it doesn't finish the download of the sources, isn't there a way to download the sources first and install them with rbenv? Or install Ruby with another method and make rbenv recognize it?

Comment: Can you show the logs at /tmp/ruby-build.20170825083100.28792.log?

Comment: Have you tried it multiple times? It could be your internet connection.

Comment: I second @MSathieu. I would give it a try again at a later time.

Comment: @vee i have deleted my answer. Probably you're more clever to answer this question.

Comment: @Roshan, some questions can just be answered in comments. I'm not at all clever.

Comment: @vee I know it's irrelevant but if you read the placeholder in the comment textarea, it says "avoid answering questions in comments".

Comment: @Roshan it is also not sure that it works, it is just to know if he already tried it.

Comment: Yeah I've tried it a couple of times, but truth be told my internet connection is really really slow, like 5-50kb/s slow.  The top speed that I've seen it in is 103kb/s.

Comment: Because of that I want to know if there are any alternatives using rbenv.